# How to integrate $ \int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt $

Tags: integration

I would like to perform the following integration

$$ \int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt $$

But the power of $n$ has thrown me.  If it was a number I would just multiply it out.  But I don't know where to start with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expand it out? Just substitute $u=x-t$ and use the power  rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See that $n$ is a constant, independent of $x$. Therefore, 
$$\int^x_a\dfrac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt=\dfrac{1}{n!}\int^x_a(x-t)^ndt=\\
-\left[\dfrac{(x-t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)n!}\right]^x_a=-\dfrac{(t-t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}-\dfrac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}=\\
\boxed{\dfrac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}}$$

Comment: Thanks, I am unsure how you get to the second line though.   Is $ \int(x-t)^ndt=-\frac{(x-t)^{n+1}}{n+1} $ a standard integral?  It isn't in the table I have, which is about as much as I know about integrals unfortunately.

Comment: @user2646276 Well, you can make it into a standard integral by $u$-substitution: $u=x-t,du=-dt$.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \int_a^x\frac{(x-t)^n}{n!}dt =-\frac{(x-t)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\Bigg|_a^x =\frac{(x-a)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

Comment: Well done, Sami, and so succinctly, too!